# How do I combine a shared object (.so) and a static library (.a) into a new shared object?

Tags: c, linux

I have a library; call it `libdog.so`.
I do not have the source to `libdog.so`.
I do not have the `.o` files which went into `libdog.so`.

```
ldd libdog.so
libdogfood.so.1 => not found
```

libdog depends on libdogfood.
I have a static dogfood library, `libdogfood.a` and `libdogfood.la`.

I want to create a new library, `libcompletedog.so`, which has no
dependency on libdogfood.

I want libcompletedog to include all symbols from libdogfood.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but the "Related" questions along the right-hand side here sure have some relevant looking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most UNIX systems (AIX is the exception) consider `.so` libraries a "final" product of the link, that can not be relinked into something else.

If your `libdogfood.a` is a 32-bit library, you might be able to link it into `libdogfood.so.1`, and thus satisfy the missing dependency:

```
gcc -shared -o libdogfood.so.1 \
 -Wl,--whole-archive libdogfood.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

If `libdogfood.a` contains 64-bit objects, above may still work (if the objects were compiled with `-fPIC`), but that's somewhat unlikely.

Comment: AFAIK `-fPIC` plays an important role irrespective of 32 or 64 bit. Even if `libdogfood.a` is a 32-bit library, if the objects part of it are compiled without `-fPIC` then this might not work.

Comment: @another.anon.coward `-fPIC` *does* play a role in 32-bit binaries as well, but you *can* build a 32-bit shared library from objects compiled without `-fPIC`. You *can't* do the same for 64-bit binaries though.

Comment: Oh is it? I have had problems with them in the past on 32 bit libraries. Maybe if I happen to encounter again I'll post something. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot do that, because `libdog.so` was compiled with `-fPIC` while `libdogfood.a` wasn't. Shared libraries need (in practice) to contain only [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code)
(otherwise there is too much relocation information inside them)

Comment: It is indeed incorrect in principle, but it is correct in practice. You really don't want lots of relocation information in a non PIC *.so